# GL_INVALID_VALUE of parameter GLsizeiptr in glBufferData function

Tags: python, opengl, pyrender

I'm trying to render a mesh as depth maps using `pyrender`, in which it calls `glBufferData` like this

```
glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, FLOAT_SZ * len(vertex_data),
        vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW
)
```

However, it throws `GL_INVALID_VALUE` when the second parameter `FLOAT_SZ * len(vertex_data)` exceeds the range of `GLsizeiptr`,

```
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1281,
        description = b'invalid value',
        baseOperation = glBufferData,
        pyArgs = (
                GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                2202722400,
                array([ -9.20932  ,   1.6728516, 499.41064  , ...,   1.       ,
         1.       ,   1.       ], dtype=float32),
                GL_STATIC_DRAW,
        ),
```

```
(Pdb) GLsizeiptr(2202722400)
c_int(-2092244896)
```

So is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: @colorfulgreen: This seems to be a bug in pyrender. `GLsizeiptr` is required by the specification to be an integer big enough to store all of the bits of a pointer. Assuming that Python is compiled as a 64-bit application, that would be a 64-bit integer. So pyrender seems to be mangling the value.